# New-CimSession not available on Windows 7?

Tags: powershell, windows-7, wmi

I'm trying to use WMI with PowerShell. In order to connect another computer, I use

```
$CimSession = New-CimSession -ComputerName 127.0.0.1
```

But I got an error:

> The term 'New-CimSession' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 originally came with PowerShell version 2, whereas **the `New-CimSession` cmdlet was [introduced in PowerShell version 3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2012/08/24/introduction-to-cim-cmdlets/)**.

You can upgrade your Windows 7 computer (SP1 or higher) to PowerShell version 5.1 (the current version as of this writing) with [this download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616). For an overview of the available upgrade options [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/setup/installing-windows-powershell#upgrading-existing-windows-powershell).